# Get Kendo NumericTextBox value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I just have a simple Kendo NumericTextBox that will store an int. All I need to know is how to get this value and assign it to a javascript variable using Jquery.

Here is my Kendo NumericTextBox:

```
<div id="Status" style="display: none">
    @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.RequestStatus)
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
var status = $("#Status").val();
var status = $("#Status").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
```

I have tried adding this to the NumericTextBox:

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "Status" })
```

Also tried adding:

```
.Name("Status")
```

I have even tried replacing "Status" with the variable name "RequestStatus".

I have looked all over, but can't find anything that actually works.

EDIT:

I have come up with a solution.

I have moved the function to the an ajax call where I get all the values for my partial view. From there I was able to use:

```
var status = data.Data[0].RequestStatus;
```

Thank you all for the replies, and for your help. Not quite sure what was going on.

Comment: You're close with the second attempt, but `#Status` should be `#RequestStatus`, as in `var status = $("#RequestStatus").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();`

Comment: I have tried that. (I have even tried replacing "Status" with the variable name "RequestStatus".) as seen above. But thank you for the reply.

Comment: Are you trying to get the value while the 'Status' div is set to `display: none`?

Comment: My best advice would be to open the developer tool in your browser. Find the NumericTextBox in the code and see what the `id` value is. Then in your javascript try something like `$("#IdValue").val()`. The way you're doing it now with the ajax call sounds very overkill for just getting the value.

Comment: It would be overkill if I was only doing the ajax request just to get that specific value, but I already had an ajax request getting multiple values for the form, so all I had to do was add this function to it.

Answer (score 2):

It should work. Only thing I can think of is we need to place those Kendo related script inside document ready function.

```
@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.RequestStatus)

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var status = $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.RequestStatus)")
             .data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
        console.log(status);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

In your code textbox is not showing because in css display:none is there.

.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m=>m.RequestStatus)
        .HtmlAttributes(new {id="Status"})
    )
```

.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var status = $("#Status").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value();
            alert(status);
    });
</script>
```